# Is there a way to abort the execution completely in QAS ?

Tags: java, qaf, qas

I'm using QAS latest version. I'm facing trouble with aborting the execution.
Lets say i have 10 test in testng.xml file and executing all of them at a time.

While first test is in execution i face some issue and have to stop the execution. I'm able to terminate the current execution by click Terminate `red button in QAS console window` but for remain test it continue open the browser one by one as many time as test remained and i have to manually close the browser.

Comment: Did you find this behavior only in qas or also in eclipse as well?

Comment: @user861594, I guess this is not QAS specific. because if i execute project as jenkins job and abort build there, it still keep running and open the browser and executed test for remaining one. May be issue in QAF or something else